# How to get collection of ids in desc order?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, collection, filter

I'm trying to get a collection/list of subcategories in desc order.

```
$subrategories = $brategory->getChildrenCategories()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('show_brand', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToSort('position','desc');
```

but it still creating collection in the same order, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `getChildrenCategories` won't work, because the method looks like this:

```
public function getChildrenCategories()
{
    return $this->getResource()->getChildrenCategories($this);
}
```

and the method `getChildrenCategories` that is called from the resource model looks like this:

```
public function getChildrenCategories($category)
{
    $collection = $this->_getChildrenCategoriesBase($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
        ->load();

    return $collection;
}
```

Notice the `load` in there. Anything you add to the collection query after the `load` call is ignored.
You can try it like this:

```
$subrategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $brategory->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('show_brand', array('eq' => 1))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //needed only if you want only the active categories
        ->addAttributeToSort('position','desc')
        ->joinUrlRewrite() //only if you want the urls of the categories
        ;
```

Comment: so if it is only one category if I replace "$brategory->getId()" with category number should work right ?

Comment: Works as a charm, Thank you Marius and of course thank you for proper explanation of how it works.